# Problems with sending an email

Tags: c#, email, backend

I am working with C# and I am trying to send an email form a web page. I am trying to populate the from email address from a textbox and the to email address is being hard coded. My code is as follows and the errors I am getting are after the code.

```
try
    {
        MailMessage oMsg = new MailMessage();
        // TODO: Replace with sender e-mail address. Get from textbox: string SenderEmail = emailbox.text
        oMsg.From = emailbox.Text; //Senders email
        // TODO: Replace with recipient e-mail address.
        oMsg.To = "DummyRecipient@gmail.com"; //Recipient email
        oMsg.Subject = subjecttbox.Text; //Subject of email

        // SEND IN HTML FORMAT (comment this line to send plain text).
        //oMsg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

        // HTML Body (remove HTML tags for plain text).
        oMsg.Body = EmailBody; //Body of the email

        // ADD AN ATTACHMENT.
        // TODO: Replace with path to attachment.
        //String sFile = @"C:\temp\Hello.txt";  
        //MailAttachment oAttch = new MailAttachment(sFile, MailEncoding.Base64);

        //oMsg.Attachments.Add(oAttch);

        // TODO: Replace with the name of your remote SMTP server.
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        //SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "Smtp.gmail.com"; //Email server name, Gmail = Smtp.gmail.com

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("DummySenderAddress@gmail.com", "DummyPassword");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpMail.Send(oMsg);

        oMsg = null;
        //oAttch = null;
    }
    catch //(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
    }
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' Property or indexer
>   'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.To' cannot be assigned to -- it is read
>   only
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection' The name 'SmtpMail' does not
>   exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your line:

```
oMsg.To = "DummyRecipient@gmail.com"; //Recipient email
```

Emails can have more than one recipient. Therefore the "To" property of the MailMessage class is a collection. Not a single email address.

Additionally, you need to create a MailAddress object instead of just using a string for the email.

Use the following line instead of the above.

```
oMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("DummyRecipient@gmail.com")); //Recipient email
```

Answer (score 1):

oMsg.From takes a MailAddress object as its input, not a string. Replace it with:

```
oMsg.From = new MailAddress(emailbox.Text);
```

oMsg.To takes a MailAddressCollection as its input.  Assuming that collection isn't null, you should be able to replace it with:

```
oMsg.To.Add("DummyRecipient@gmail.com");
```